# How to create normal project directories from the svn version?

Tags: svn

I am working on a project that is SVN controlled, but as now i want to publish my project, i don't want my final project should contain ".svn" folders in them. Can you please suggest me the way to remove all those folders, so that i can deliver my project. But the final project must be separate directory structure, so that i don't disturb the original svn structure.
I am working on PHP with Netbeans.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the `svn export` command.

[svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html) will export a complete copy of your code tree, without any .svn directories or source control.